How to pass a data in the modeless dialog window in Windows Desktop App (MFC, C++)?
The situation is quite simple, yet I don't understand in quite well.
I have a WinMFC app, which is also a name of the solution project. I want to pass the data from Main dialog of the app (WinMFCDialog.cpp + WinMFCDialog.h) into the modeless custom dialog (CustomDialog.cpp + CustomDialog.h)
Modeless means that the CustomDialog is functioning as a separate window, without catching focus on itself, so I can interact with WinMFCDialog separately.
Here are the codes:
WinMFCDlg.h
#pragma once

class CWinMFCDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CWinMFCDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   

    enum { IDD = IDD_WINMFC_DIALOG };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    


protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton1();
};

WinMFCDlg.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "WinMFC.h"
#include "WinMFCDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "CustomDialog.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialogEx(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CWinMFCDlg::CWinMFCDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/): 
    CDialogEx(CWinMFCDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CWinMFCDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CWinMFCDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CWinMFCDlg::OnBnClickedButton1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CWinMFCDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        

    return TRUE;
}

void CWinMFCDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

void CWinMFCDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this);

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Нарисуйте значок
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

HCURSOR CWinMFCDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}


void CWinMFCDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // Modeless dialog, in which I want to pass the data
    CustomDialog *pDlg = new CustomDialog();
    pDlg->Create(IDD_CUSTOM_DIALOG, this);
    pDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}

CustomDialog.h
#pragma once

class CustomDialog : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CustomDialog)

public:
    CustomDialog(CWnd* pParent = NULL);
    virtual ~CustomDialog();

    enum { IDD = IDD_CUSTOM_DIALOG };

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CustomDialog.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "WinMFC.h"
#include "CustomDialog.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CustomDialog, CDialog)

CustomDialog::CustomDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CustomDialog::IDD, pParent)
{

}

CustomDialog::~CustomDialog()
{
}

void CustomDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CustomDialog, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

WinMFC.h (main app, just in case)
#pragma once

#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
    #error "включить stdafx.h до включения этого файла в PCH"
#endif

#include "resource.h"

class CWinMFCApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    CWinMFCApp();

public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

extern CWinMFCApp theApp;

WinMFC.cpp (main app, just in case)
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "WinMFC.h"
#include "WinMFCDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

// CWinMFCApp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CWinMFCApp, CWinApp)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, &CWinApp::OnHelp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// Craetion of CWinMFCApp
CWinMFCApp::CWinMFCApp()
{
    m_dwRestartManagerSupportFlags = AFX_RESTART_MANAGER_SUPPORT_RESTART;
}

// Single object CWinMFCApp
CWinMFCApp theApp;

// Initialization of CWinMFCApp
BOOL CWinMFCApp::InitInstance()
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);

    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

    CWinApp::InitInstance();
    AfxEnableControlContainer();
    CShellManager *pShellManager = new CShellManager;
    SetRegistryKey(_T("Test MFC APP"));

    CWinMFCDlg dlg;
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
    if (nResponse == IDOK)
    {
    }
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
    {
    }

    if (pShellManager != NULL)
    {
        delete pShellManager;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

I input the data into the edit box, which is created in WinMFCDlg:

The data should be displayed after in CustomDialog in a static field element:

So, I tried to use DDX/DDV functions to pass the data from edit text of the WinMFC dialog into the static text field of Custom dialog.
This is what I tried to do:

I added the signature of the function below into the WinMFCh (not in the class, so, it's not a method)

void DDX_TextNotEmpty (CDataExchange* pDX, int nIDC, CString& value);
class CWinMFCApp : public CWinApp
{
// Class definition
}


I wrote the realization of it in WinMFC.cpp

void DDX_TextNotEmpty (CDataExchange* pDX, int nIDC, CString& value)
{
    HWND hWndCtrl = pDX->PrepareEditCtrl(nIDC);
    if (pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate)
    {
        int nLen = ::GetWindowTextLength(hWndCtrl);
        ::GetWindowText(hWndCtrl, value.GetBufferSetLength(nLen), nLen+1);
        value.ReleaseBuffer();
        if (value.IsEmpty ())
        {
            AfxMessageBox (_T("Enter something in the text field."), MB_ICONSTOP);
            pDX->Fail ();   //Fail () sets the focus on to the edit control
        }
    }
    else { ::SetWindowText(hWndCtrl, value); }
}


In the CustomDialog.h I added a public member, which should store the received data:

class CustomDialog : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CustomDialog)

public:
    CString m_string;
    CustomDialog(CWnd* pParent = NULL);

// ... Default stuff created by VS2010 ...
}


After I modified default constructor to set the member value by default in CustomDialog.cpp

CustomDialog::CustomDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CustomDialog::IDD, pParent), m_string(_T("default value"))
{

}


I after try to call that function in CustomDialog.cpp

void CustomDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_TextNotEmpty(pDX, IDC_EDIT_DATA, m_string);
}


In the end I received an error:

Well, I don't know what actually I did wrong, so I hope that my question is not drastically stupid or annoying to ask, I just want to learn how to use this old but interesting stuff .
Will be glad for any help.

A side note: why do you use such an ancient VS version (you tagged vs-2010) ?

Also: did you try to hit the "Debug" button in the asserttion dialog ? It should break with the debugger at the point that violated the assertion.

You can pass arbitrary data into a dialog by supplying a custom constructor receiving that data (or providing class members to populate the data after the dialog class has been instantiated). You can diagnose the specific error you receive by pressing "Debug". That'll take you to the debug assertion in the code that failed.

Click on the "Debug"  (whatever that is in your language). It will show the MFC source line where the problem occurs. This will help you (and us) to find what the problem is. Also look at the stack trace which will help you to find which line of your source code triggered the problem. [Edit] the question and provide that information.

I solved the huuuge part of the problem . Now my data passes into, but not as I wanted.
I understood that the problem was that I was calling DDX_TextNotEmpty(pDX, IDC_EDIT_DATA, m_string) in a dialog, which was not created yet! I discovered it though DEBUG mode. But the result is still not what I wanted .
I want to get sort of an automatic update: the text got automatically updated in a modal dialog when I input a text into the edit box in the main dialog. For now I can update it only via button in the main dialog: m_ptrDialog->SetDlgItemTextW(IDC_STATIC, m_string);

... Okay, this is what I figured out ...
The problem was that I was calling DDX_TextNotEmpty(pDX, IDC_EDIT_DATA, m_string) in a dialog, which was not created yet (in my case in CustomDialog). Besides, I used it wrong as well . This function is like a binding in Android development. By that I mean that it updates variable (m_string) when it got changed in UI. But, thanks to Constantine Georgiou, there is a built-in DDX_Text, So no need to use that function in WinMFCDlg.cpp. So now it looks like this:
void CWinMFCDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
 CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
 DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT_DATA, m_string);
}

So, in order to pass the data into the modal I need to put my string inside of the static text element in my modal dialog, which I do by pressing the button in the WinMFCDlg, also updating it from UI. In order to keep the only one modal dialog instead of opening it several times I added CustomDialog as a field in the WinMFCDlg class:
class CWinMFCDlg : public CDialogEx
{
   public:
    CustomDialog* m_ptrDialog;
    // Don't forget to delete it
    virtual ~CWinMFCDlg(){ delete m_ptrDialog; }
   // Other stuff...
}

After I initialize the pointer in the BOOL CWinMFCDlg::OnInitDialog() in WinMFCDlg.cpp like this:
BOOL CWinMFCDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
  CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

  // ...default initialization...

  m_ptrDialog = new CustomDialog();
  m_ptrDialog->Create(IDD_CUSTOM_DIALOG, this);
  return TRUE;
}

And finally, in order to put my data into a modal dialog I simply press the button in the WinMFCDlg:
void CWinMFCDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
   UpdateData(TRUE);
   // Modeless dialog
   m_ptrDialog->SetDlgItemTextW(IDC_STATIC, m_string);
   m_ptrDialog->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}

... and see the result: here it is
Which is what I wanted! But not in the exact way that I wanted... Well, if I figure this 'automatic-update-that-I-want-to-get' out, I will add the solution here .
 I FIGURED IT OUT! 
The key was in event, which EditControl can handle. There is two of them: EN_CHANGE and EN_UPDATE:

EN_CHANGE - The display is updated after text changed;
EN_UPDATE - Edit control is about to display altered text.

Still don't quite understand what is might be the most suitable in my case, anyway, it works.
Here is what I added in WinMFCDlg.cpp:
void CWinMFCDlg::OnEnChangeEditData()
{
    // TODO:  If this is a RICHEDIT control, the control will not
    // send this notification unless you override the CDialogEx::OnInitDialog()
    // function and call CRichEditCtrl().SetEventMask()
    // with the ENM_CHANGE flag ORed into the mask.

    // TODO:  Add your control notification handler code here
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    m_ptrDialog->SetDlgItemTextW(IDC_STATIC, m_string);
}


Do not assume a binding mechanism like that on Android or .NET; no "automatic" updates here. MFC instead provides the UpdateData() method, which updates the member variables or the controls. UpdateData(FALSE) means variables->controls, while UpdateData(TRUE) means controls->variables - includes "validation". The default implementation of OnOK() calls UpdateData(TRUE), and if all validations are passed closes the dialog.

The easiest way to pass data to a MFC dialog is as data members, set after the constructor call and of course before the Create()or DoModal() call. You may elect to pass copies of your data or references (eg pointers) to data maintained by the parent dialog, document or application. On close (after the OnOK() or OnCancel() call), you can copy the data in the member variables back to the parent (before the destructor call). This is how it's done in most DDX/DDV examples. For example:
COptionsDialog dlg;                     // Constructor
dlg.m_DataDir = m_Options.sDataDir;     // Pass Data to the dialog class
if (dlg.DoModal()==IDOK)                // Display the dialog
{
    m_Options.sDataDir = dlg.m_DataDir; // Copy modified data back to the parent
}

The problem you are facing may have to do with calling PrepareEditCtrl() for a non-editable control (static text). Try PrepareCtrl() instead. Or replace the DDX_TextNotEmpty() call with a simple DDX_Text() one, without validation (DDV_()); how could the system "validate" input from a control that doesn't allow user input?
A side note, you should destroy the instance of the CustomDialog class (you created it with new) after you are done with it.

I don't quite understand what do you mean by m_Options.sDataDir? What is actually suppose to be?

@DOJ, nothing to do with your post, just an example. The app is supposed to keep the "Application Options" in the m_Options structure. One if its members is the "Data Directory" (ie the folder where data files are located), stored in the sDataDir member (it's a "path"). The example just demonstrates how such data can be transferred to and from the dialog. As for your proposed solution, you should rather implement a DDV_TextNotEmpty() (ie validation-only, called after a DDX_Text() call). Just check the DDV_MaxChars() code and modify it so as to check for empty text instead.
